# Can/should "dead links" in locked posts be removed?

Tags: discussion, locked-posts, broken-link

I just stumbled upon [this locked, closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163173/why-use-gradle-instead-of-ant-or-maven).
It contains the following "dead" link:

> [Why use Buildr instead of Ant or Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015525/why-use-buildr-instead-of-ant-or-maven)

which leads to a "Page Not Found".

I don't know how such things are handled on Stack Overflow, and that's why I have to ask: Even though the question is just kept "because it has historical significance", shouldn't there be a way to update/remove/comment dead links?

Answer (score 13):

The link isn't really dead. It's just you don't have the privilege to see deleted questions in the SO site:

[image]

Good question though what should be done with the link.

> Does it actually add any essential information?

No.

> Could the question just stand for itself without it?

Yes.

**Conclusion:**

Remove the link entirely. You need to flag for a moderator's help to do this.

Comment: But how to remove the link? The question is locked, which states "This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed.". Can anyone with higher privleges can edit locked questions?

Comment: @MarkusWeninger I added what to do.

Comment: Just saw your edit, thanks, will flag it.

Comment: So, next question, sorry: I do not have a "flag" button below the question, only a "share" one. So I am also not able to flag it. Or am I missing something? I think this will also have to do with privileges?

Comment: @MarkusWeninger No, you're right. I put an appropriate flag request at the 1st comment now. You may do the same.

Comment: Also issued the flag on the first comment with regard to this discussion. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger Good so, I also referred to here.

Comment: So, this doesn't stop to bother me: I just checked my casted flags, and now I have to see that my flag has been "declined". 'So I have to assume that your suggested approach is also not perfect...

Comment: @MarkusWeninger Well, mine was declined also. So it seems mods decided this isn't really an issue. I'm afraid there's nothing more that can be done. If we are luck a mod may come here and clarify (you should unacceptt my answer).

Comment: Maybe before removing the link it should be checked if the contents are moved somewhere else or are available on archive.org

Comment: @MrTux I already made clear where the link _moved_, its a deleted question.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger Despite our flags were declined, the link is gone now.

Comment: Until the clarification by a mod we will probably stay in the dark if we acted correct or what the real correct way would have been. But thanks for all your help. :)

Comment: `the SO network` The network is **Stack Exchange**, not **Stack Overflow**!

Answer (score 9):

### This specific case

In this specific instance: The link is to a deleted Stack Overflow question. As [πάντα ῥεῖ mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333436/3773011), the link should probably be removed. The link is to a question Stack Overflow is choosing not to show.  Within our own content, links to such deleted questions should be removed.

Note: It should be removed when the link is sending people there for more information that used to be contained in the question. The link should not be removed from Meta posts which are discussing the deleted question.

### In general, find an archive of the link

The author of the post put the link in the post for a reason. In general, we are not supposed to change the author's intent.  Thus, if you can find one, the link should be updated to an archive of the page that was linked.

Probably the best solution is to link to a copy of the page that is as close as possible to what the page was when the OP added the link. You will need to explore the edit history of the post to see when the link was added.  In this instance, it would be:

[Why use Buildr instead of Ant or Maven? (Archive as of 2009-07-03)](https://web.archive.org/web/20090703052824/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015525/why-use-buildr-instead-of-ant-or-maven)

Alternately, you could use the most recent archive prior to the page going dead:

[Why use Buildr instead of Ant or Maven? (Archive as of 2013-12-25)](https://web.archive.org/web/20131225234957/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015525/why-use-buildr-instead-of-ant-or-maven)

Using an archive other than the one closest to when the OP added the link to the post is a judgement call.  The OP, obviously, put the link in the post with the content as it was on the date of inserting the link.  Using a more recent archive may, or may not, preserve the OP's intent. You will have to use your own judgement.

### Finding archives

To find archives I use some [bookmarklets](https://www.google.com/search?q=bookmarklet) to look for archives of the page currently being displayed.  Those bookmarklets are:

Find archive.org archives:

```
javascript:void(window.open('https://web.archive.org/web/*/'+location.href))
```

Find Mementos (searches multiple archive sites):

```
javascript:void(window.open('https://www.webarchive.org.uk/mementos/search/'+location.href+'?referrer='+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)))
```

Find archives on webcitation.org:

```
javascript:void(window.open('https://www.webcitation.org/query.php?url='+location.href))
```

Find archives on archive.wikiwix.com:

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://archive.wikiwix.com/cache/?url='+location.href))
```

### Making the actual change

Because the post is locked, you will need to raise a custom moderator flag on something else (flagging is not an option for locked posts). The first comment on the post would probably be a good option as to where to raise the flag. Be sure to include a link or description to the post that has the problem, the specific link within the post that is an issue and the archive URL (or that you believe the link should be deleted).

Comment: Thanks for the bookmarklets - I've immediately added them to my bookmark collection ;)