# How do I deal with old answers containing broken links?

Tags: discussion, flags, broken-link, faq-proposed, psa

I found some old answer that contains a broken link. What do I do about that? Should I flag it?

(There is [this closely related Q/A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262038/how-to-flag-dead-links). But it comes from a different starting point with OP already being aware of the possibility of updating the link. Given the volume of related flags we get in the custom queue, a Q/A from a more basic starting point appears to make sense.)

Comment: simple try to fix it

Comment: Should this be a FAQ request?

Comment: Just edit the answer and put a Wayback Machine archive URL in its place. You should usually be able to find one.

Comment: You should tag this as `faq`.

Comment: There is no harm to write a comment. If answer is not useful without the working link, then just downvote it. Some *old* post aren't really worth to worry much ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/461857/1997232)).

Answer (score 54):

Broken links in answers generally do not require moderator attention. If you suspect intentional spam, do flag accordingly, but otherwise:

- Check if the answer is valid without the link. If it is not:

  - If there is proven value in the answer, e.g. indicated by a high score and it being used as a dupe target, try to [fix the answer by updating the link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323562) as discussed in more detail below. If that is not possible, custom-flag the answer for removal detailing your salvaging efforts.
  - Otherwise, flag it as Not An Answer to get the link-only answer removed.
- If the answer is still valid without the link:

  - If the resource has moved and you can find out where, (suggest an) edit updating the link accordingly.
  - If the link went dead for some reason (including the domain being snatched up and changed or  redirected to questionable sites) try to [find some archive link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333503/) that preserves the author's original intent.
  - If finding a good archive link fails, simply edit out the offending link.

As usual, once you fixed some problem with an answer, flag comments referring to that problem as No Longer Needed.

Comment: If the answer can't survive without the link, it should be flagged anyway...

Comment: @Anonymous-ReinstatetheCafé By the Meta discussions so far: It depends. There is the [linked Q/A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323508/what-to-do-with-broken-but-highly-upvoted-link-only-answers/323562#323562) that details some criteria where by votes it was determined we don't want to apply that rule indiscriminately. Even on [the most likely canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251514/how-should-accepted-link-only-answers-be-handled) there was some debate. But that's a discussion for another thread.

Comment: Would it not also be appropriate to quote the relevant parts of the link (if you can) as well; provided that the content needed to be copied isn't huge paragraphs? Then if the link goes dead again in the future the impact on the answer is far smaller

Comment: @Larnu Of course, any further improvement of the post when editing is very welcome.

Comment: "Check if the answer is valid.." Maybe valid should be defined in that context. According to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer every attempt at an answer is an answer. Maybe simply write: Does it still attempt to answer the question even after removal of the link? Yes ... /No ....

Comment: @Trilarion if it doesn't answer the question without the link, it was never really a proper answer to begin with.

Answer (score 37):

The [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) caches a lot of old web pages.  If you can find the content there, a link to it can substitute for the broken link.  If you have enough reputation you can edit the link directly, or you can suggest an edit to fix the link.

Comment: I think this is covered in the 2nd link in the above answer

Comment: @Yatin having an answer buried in the middle of a lot of other content isn't as useful as having it stated directly.

Comment: I've even used the forward history feature in wayback along with some ddg searching to find the new canonical and linked both the archive and what seems like the new canonical in an edit

Comment: @Lazerbeak Could you elaborate on how to do that? I use Wayback a lot and "forward history"/ddg aren't terms I'm familiar with. Are you talking about looking for the time at which the old URL started redirecting to another?

Comment: @Yatin I think Mark makes the key point here a lot more clearly than the previous answer did. To be honest, this is the thing you should do pretty much every time you encounter a dead link, so instead of being buried in another answer it should be right at the start.

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica Yes, I understood. I am one of the 21 upvotes on their comment ;)

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica DDG is DuckDuckGo. The "forward history" referrs to the navigation on wayback that lets you see newer captures of the same page.