# How to improve vague references to comments/post in a post that use variables like username or position?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, psa

People have the habit of referring to answers/comments in the below fashion. This has some problems (as stated under each one)

> *The other answer under this question says that <...>*
> This assumes that more answers will not be added

> *The third answer from the top is correct but <...>*
> This assumes that the visitor is using the same ordering and that future voting will not cause a position change

> *The most upvoted answer is wrong.*
> This assumes that other answers can't overtake it

> *The accepted answer is outdated.*
> This assumes that the author of the question won't suddenly change their mind

> *The answer by <username> is correct for the most part but needs these improvements <...>*
> This assumes that the username will not be changed

> *The comment under this post makes a valid point.*
> This assumes that the comment won't be deleted

> *The comment by <username> suggests that <...>*
> This assumes that the username won't be changed

Lines like these assume that the indicator they are relying on (the username, the relative position of the post/comment with respect to the current post, the number of upvotes, the accepted check-mark, the number of answers under the post) are constants and will not change with time - which is not true.

Usernames change. The order of the answers depends on the net score of the post and the ordering choice of the viewer. The number of upvotes changes with time and a *lower-ranking* post now might *win* later on and replace the highest upvoted post. The *'acceptance'*  of a post is solely dependent on the author of the question's very human (susceptible to change) mood. New answers can be added in the future (hence changing the total number of answers).

Some *real* examples to express myself better:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67877994/11573842) by [Antonio Bakula](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351383/antonio-bakula) says: *"(like one in most upvoted answer)"* - I have no idea which answer they are referring to as the most upvoted answer can change.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68513890/11573842) by [Marcel Degas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68513890/11573842) says: *"the most upvoted answer for that post was not super clear and there was no code example"* and links to a post - on that post I find 7 answers. The [current most upvoted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38157268/11573842) has a line of code in it. Now I need to guess what they meant by "there was no code example" and what is and isn't considered as a "code example". This would have been so much more easier if they would have just linked to the answer that they were referring to...
- Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37197370/11573842) that was written by [michaelgmcd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3022545/michaelgmcd) - which originally inspired me to write this post - says: *"but seeing that the other (albeit more upvoted answer)"* while it itself is the most upvoted answer! How am I supposed to know what they were referring to? Being <10k how do I know if that answer isn't deleted?

[Search result of "most upvoted answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=most%20upvoted%20answer&searchOn=1) for example.

My point being that improper referencing of this sort is way too common and as time goes on it can become a big issue where no one is sure who is referring to who. How can we resolve this?

Comment: "*People have a habit of referring to usernames in posts by adding a @ symbol before them: '@<username> says that...'. *" this has some historical traction to it. There were multiple platforms where usernames would start with an @. This isn't exactly still the case but you *can* use @ to explicitly mention some user in different platforms. Like in comments here and some chat platforms. So, it has become an internet "slang" when talking about users. It does make it easier to distinguish usernames from other words that are not usernames.

Comment: "*So I generally remove them while editing.*" That's also fine, IMO. We don't *need* to use @ everywhere. It's a bit "archaic" in Internet use. I personally like to format usernames in bold or (if available) underline. That way they are visually distinguishable and it's easy to see that I'm not just using a word but it's a special term. Context will make it clear it's another user.

Comment: When talking about comments in answers, it's even better to just quote the comment, as comments should be considered temporary... They can disappear at any moment.

Comment: I also never have noticed this to be a significant issue...

Comment: Also, your minor suggestion about the `@`: It's a visual indicator that we're talking about a username. A link to the actual user is better (as names can be changed), so don't _only_ remove the `@` when editing. (Either add a link or don't change it)

Comment: Wouldn't this be better formatted as a separate question (how to refer to other answers) and answer (with your suggestions)? Then it would actually allow alternative recommendations and voting on them.

Comment: Seems like a bit of a rant to me. Personally, I like referring to users in answers using `@` as @Cerbrus says it's a visual indicator we are talking about a username. The other point about linking comments is valid though and I’ve been doing that since I first came to site.

Comment: @jpa um... I am not sure... Alternate recommendations can still be provided as answers/comments and voting can still be done normally on this post.. (I think... I have never written a PSA before.. I went ahead and re-read the tag wiki and consulted a few other PSAs and this seems to be the norm. Please let me know if this isn't how it should be done...)

Comment: @user692942 I didn't mean this as a rant.. More of a suggestion on to how to improve referencing so that it is easier for the visitor to understand. Also please see my edit on the last point.. I tried clarifying a few things...

Comment: If many people disagree with the last point then I'll happily remove it. It was supposed to be a minor suggestion after all and the post can live without it

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 I think the format used in e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407312/how-do-i-deal-with-old-answers-containing-broken-links is better. But just my opinion. Currently I would upvote your post for "this is important issue" but downvote for "I don't agree with the suggested fixes".

Comment: Isn't "this <reference>" just noise anyway? Comments can vanish, answers can be edited, people can change their opinion. Don't refer to comments/answers *better*, instead don't refer to the at all.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It's kind of hard to have a good *repository of knowledge* if the knowledge can disappear. Yes, it *does* happen but I've not seen it on such a massive scale to just expect posts to suddenly never be relevant again.

Comment: @VLAZ Comments do disappear. Outdated and wrong answers *hopefully* get edited.  It's kind of hard to have a good repository of knowledge if the knowledge is wrong.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, and a second answer that says "X is outdated" can also be edited. I don't see a huge issue. I think that more often people say "See <this answer>" as a *good* example of how something is done. And good answers tend to stay good even after being edited.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi say I write an answer and someone comments underneath it. I really like what they have written and want to include it in my answer but according to your comment, I can't. Which seems like the opposite thing I should do if I want to preserve it. Preserving it needs me to copy the content into the post and that needs attribution.. Or say that I wish to add an alternate solution to an answer provided by someone but at the same time I want to include parts of what they have written. I will need to link to their answer again for attribution..

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 If you include a comment verbatim, then it is a *quote* and as such needs to be attributed *as per its license*. If they just gave you a good idea what to write yourself, I don't see a point in referring to them at all – in fact as someone on the receiving end I am often annoyed as being "cited" as a source of facts when I'm just the middleman.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Just doing the very minimal required doesn't mean it's not confusing. You can easily quote a [comment](www.example.com) verbatim and link to it at the same time. Then everyone clicking on the link will know exactly which post is was on.

Comment: @VLAZ I can't say I remember seeing any worthwhile "See <this example>" cases. References in the new examples of this Meta Q all seem like meta commentary: ["someone did it wrong"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276355/can-i-access-session-state-from-an-httpmodule/67877994#67877994), ["something I don't get"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68492725/how-to-return-a-response-from-rails-api-with-activerecord-relations-2-levels-dee/68513890#68513890), ["something I don't like"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195590/how-can-i-persist-redux-state-tree-on-refresh/37197370#37197370).

Comment: @Scratte I think you misunderstand what I mean by proper attribution if you call it "doing the very minimal required" –– [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410553/dont-refer-to-comments-or-other-answers-by-variables-like-position-or-username#comment858564_410553) by [Scratte](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte). While this is often handled with leniency on [SO], [attribution is required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/?_ga=2.153822776.1829322861.1627923028-2087842276.1627923028) by the license.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I see. Sorry, yes I misunderstood. I tend to always link to the user and to the original content myself. But I don't always link to, quote nor attribute something that just got me thinking about finding a solution. So I guess I agree with you :)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi my point isn't that you must give a reference to *every single good idea* that you have from someone else... My point is that if you are *already mentioning/referring* to someone then provide a link instead of just giving a verbal reference so that I can understand what you are saying even after a long time has passed and the scene isn't the same anymore...

Comment: Recurring favorite: "Above answer ....".

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 My point is if you are cleaning up, might as well clean up for good. It's rather telling that all three examples so far, and a lot of the search hits, just refer to other content as meta commentary. No need to polish a truly unsalvageable reference debacle, as they say.

Comment: @Yunnosch Even better: "The bellow answer..."

Comment: Whenever I see a vague reference like this, I write a comment to the author of the post to request they make the attribution more specific (rather than raise a flag).

Comment: This question contains a self-answer. Why not doing it in Q&A? You know you just broke some other rule?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate, '*I have no idea which answer they are referring to as the most upvoted answer can change.*' You can audit the scores of posts by going to the question's or answer's timeline page and seeing what score things were at at the time of the comment. Likewise you can see revision history to know whether a given answer contained code at the time of a comment.

Comment: Sorry for not separating the question and the answer from the beginning. Please vote on the question/answer on their own merits. Sorry for any inconvenience caused by me. I didn't know how PSAs were supposed to be written. I assumed that you could just write your points into the question itself. I was wrong.

Comment: This is not a minor issue nor a rant, but an incredibly important topic. The entire "comments are temporary and should be treated as such" has always had a strong whiff of fecal matter about it, because for better or worse **comments often provide vital metadata about questions and answers**. Since the Stack Overflow platform is so limited in so many ways (prime examples: being unable to change which answer is accepted in favour of a newer one; being unable to sort answers by "newest"), comments have ended up as a way to provide some of that missing functionality!

Comment: @HereticMonkey My second favorite spellchecker-undetected typo. Most favorite "doe snot".

Comment: I am seeing that close votes are slowly increasing on this question. Some advice on how to edit the question to make it on topic would be much appreciated... I for one can’t understand what is wrong with the current state of the question :/

Comment: "The comment by …" also assumes the user won't add another comment.  Likewise, "The answer by …" could also become outdated if the user adds a second answer (somewhat rare, but valid & acceptable if it's an entirely different approach to the same problem).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Please **link directly to the comments/answers that you refer to in your posts**. It takes only a few seconds but leads to a less confusing and more convenient visitor experience.

Like this:

<sub>(Where strike means 'remove the content' and closed square backets means 'add this content')</sub>

> <strike>The other</strike> [[this] answer](//) <strike>under this question</strike> says that <...>

> <strike>The third</strike> [[this] answer](//) <strike>from the top</strike> is correct but <...>

> <strike>The most upvoted</strike> [[this] answer](//) is wrong.

> <strike>The accepted</strike> [[this] answer](//) is outdated.

> [The answer](//) by [<username>](//) is correct for the most part but needs these improvements <...>

> <strike>The</strike>  [[this] comment](//)  <strike>under this post</strike> makes a valid point.

> <strike>The</strike> [[this] comment](//) by [<username>](//) suggests that <...>

*Note*: By this example, I don't mean that *all* links should follow this set format! What I mean to say is to actually link to the answer/comment instead of just giving a verbal reference. You can always phrase it into your posts as you please.

***Benefits of doing this:***

- It makes it easier and faster for visitors to find what is being referred to. And understand your post better.
- It removes the need for visitors to *guess* which answer or comment *might be* referred to.
- In the case of a deleted answer/comment having a link that leads to nowhere and a link to the user profile, from where you can find the user name, and not finding that user name on the page can help the visitor understand that the referred answer/comment is in-fact deleted (hence they won't waste their time reading every single answer/comment to guess). This is especially useful for <10k users and anonymous users - who can't see deleted answers.

***Note to editors***:

If you find a post that doesn't do this then it is a good idea to try and edit a link in. **But** make sure that *you* are clear about what is being referred to first! Otherwise, it will lead to even more confusion. If you aren't a 100% sure which comment/answer is being referred to; then ping the author of the post for clarification and only then edit the link in.

***Other remarks***:

- You can link to answers by clicking on the '*Share*' button and copying the URL to your clipboard. For comments, right-click on the timestamp next to the comment and copy the link. [See this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120688/598066).
- For comments I would highly recommend you to quote the relevant content directly in your post - it removes the need for the visitor to even click on the link and keeps your post self-sufficient as comments can disappear at any moment. But don't remove the link to the comment & username as those are needed for proper attribution! Refer: [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).
- *Minor suggestion*: People have a habit of referring to usernames in posts by adding a `@` symbol before them: *'@<username> says that...'*. This is okay but it must be noted that this doesn't really do anything unless it is used in a comment. It doesn't ping the user. Also, in my opinion, it makes the sentence grammatically wrong as the `@` symbol is read *'at'* so I end up reading the sentence *'the suggestion by @Sabito is wrong'* as *'the suggestion by at Sabito is wrong'*... So I generally remove them while editing. It is up to you if you choose to remove it or not but make sure that you at least link to the user profile as the link helps in visually separating the username from the content of the post.

Comment: I hate it when people do this. I don't want to click a random link that takes me god knows where. I've seen places where `[this] answer` isn't even on the same question! (Or even has been deleted in the interim.) Why not either A.) omit the reference entirely, or B.) summarize? ("In addition to the foobar algorithm, you could alternatively try the built-in whatsit functions added in version 3.9")

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Then don't click it.

Comment: If it's not important enough to click, we clearly should just omit it then, eh?

Comment: I would go so far as to omit the "by <username>" part as they could change their display name.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Your browser should tell you where a link is pointing to when you hover over it, without click it. It's not "a random link", it's just a normal hyperlink. Which are very much encouraged on the web.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas links are *supplementary*. Visit them if you need to learn more information. Don't visit them if you're not interested. If *all* the information in a post is a link and nothing else, it might be eligible for a link-only deletion. If you prefer that ***all the information from the link*** be put in the post, then I suggest you help me update some of my answers that refer to the ES specs. Feel free to copy and paste *the entire spec* in my answers when they refer to it, if you think that's the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: @Cave Keep it! If you include a link to their user profile, that'll still work cause it's primarily identified by ID, not name. For example, I'm [/users/4518341/wjandrea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4518341/wjandrea), but [/users/4518341/john-doe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4518341/john-doe) still refers to me by my ID, 4518341.

Comment: @wjandrea oh sure, but then the text should be something like `by this user` with `this user` linked to the user profile as you mentioned

Comment: @CaveJohnson as I stated in the note under the quotes; you can phrase the sentence however you like. The only “condition” is that *if you are referring to a user* then link to their profile. The text itself could be their username or ‘this user’ or ‘this person’ etc. Even if you refer to them as <username> and if the username later changes, at the very least, editors in the future can fix it with the latest username (or some generic phrase) later on

Answer (score 2):

Prefer to just not refer to comments or other answers or users, full stop.

---

The Q&A model of Stack Overflow is not really suitable to rely on temporary or subjective information. Comments will be deleted, and users* are not authoritative. Other answers may hold valuable content, but referring to them in a conversational or commentary style is not helpful.

If your answer has such references because they motivated you to write the answer, because they gave you a hint in the right direction, because you found them inferior or lacking, or anything else not relevant for the on-topic content of your answer, just remove these references.

If your answer relies on *content* from comments or answers, *quote* it at least in parts. Quoting involves giving proper attribution/source and also preserves/presents the relevant information. By default, content on Stack Overflow is subject to a license that *requires* proper attribution.

> As noted in the Stack Exchange Terms of Service and in the footer of every page, all publicly accessible user contributions are licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license […]
> --- Stack Overflow Help center
> , [What is the license for the content I post?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)

When other answers provide useful *background* information, just treat them like any other auxiliary resource: [add a link to them.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) Explicitly calling out that they are answers on Stack Overflow is usually not helpful; prefer to have the link text summarise the topic, message or key points supported by the link target.

---

* That is, as users of Stack Overflow. If the person themselves is an authority, they are so regardless of their status as a Stack Overflow user.

Comment: Eh, I would rather just provide linking/proper attribution *without* quoting, because quoting takes up unnecessary space. You know how much vertical space a Stack Snippet takes up? No thank you. Quoting is useful for when the content you are referring to is not available or is *not on the same page*... when referencing other answers on the same Q, they *are* available on the very same page.

Comment: @TylerH The point is that if the content is relevant for an answer, it should be in the answer itself. On the one hand that is to avoid having to jump somewhere else and back again; whether the target is on the same page or not doesn't matter for that. On the other hand, and more importantly, it is to ensure the relevant content is available as expected, no matter if the target is moved, edited or deleted.

Comment: 'relevant' is different from 'necessary'. The question is relevant to the answer, but should we quote the entire question in our answers?

Comment: @TylerH If your answer is specifically referring to some part of the question, by all means *do* quote them instead of talking about lines 12 to 47, code block 2. That's why this answer refers to quoting *parts* instead of necessarily the entire thing.