# Some new users confuse editors for answerers/askers, can a subtle design change avoid that?

Tags: discussion, design, new-users

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54247119/11573842) by [the_best](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2355055/the-best). They start their answer by saying:

> Updating Prashant Pimpale answer. Just did it a moment ago.

Now, ignoring the [improper referencing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410553/11573842) in their answer, the only other place where the name *'Prashant Pimpale'* is found under that question<sup>1</sup> is as an edit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51587560/11573842).

[image]

And I know that [Prashant doesn't have any deleted answers under that post](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52889537#52889537) so it is quite clear that the_best mistook them as the answerer of the post.

I have seen new users make this mistake quite a few times.

- Are there some **subtle**<sup>2</sup> changes that can be made to the design to make the difference between an editor and asker/answerer clear?
- What changes do you suggest?
- Are such a changes necessary and worth dev time in the first place?

<sub><sup>1</sup> which is off-topic btw</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> the current design is pretty good. I am not asking for a complete remake, just some small changes</sub>

Comment: *"Are such a changes necessary and worth dev time in the first place?"* ... they aren't, in my opinion. As you can see in your screenshot, both users are "labeled" via "edited ..." and "answered ...". There is no further distinction necessary.

Comment: That’s the first time I’ve seen someone be confused about this. Users are very rarely mentioned in posts anyway. I don’t think anything needs to be done here, other than _maybe_ edit the answer to correct the author’s name.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I've seen it a lot.. in the review queues. Especially in Late Answers

Comment: Makes me wonder how often this happens over other seemingly blatantly obvious mistakes, such as asking a question that isn't in English. But then I suppose these incidents are more easily left unnoticed than the latter.

Comment: This, in my opinion, is the fault of the user not the UI; the user simply isn't reading. I've on numerous occasions been @'ed in the comments asking about "my" answer because I commented on the answer (perhaps to suggest an improvement, or answer another comment). The answer clearly states who the author and editor is.

Comment: While I haven't encountered the supposedly many cases of "new users being confused" by this, I have always found a bit weird that the "last editor" took as much screen real-state. Personally, I think that the UI for "wiki posts" is better in that sense, making individual editors less preponderant.

Comment: there **could** be a warning displayed to the user upon matching that their answer contains "@username's answer" in case no such answer is found on the page but knowing the history of relationship of SE with regular expressions (not to mention that username changes are a can of worms on its own)...

Comment: FWIW, the positions of the last editor and the post author got swapped a few years ago. That was a bit disorienting for a while.

Comment: No amount of redesign is going to make people slow down so they don't make these kind of haste-driven-mistakes.

Comment: I have been thanked many times for an answer I didn't write. It is annoying. I immediately flag all comments that ping me. I wish the editor information would be a little less prominent, especially on mobile version where it looks like I wrote the post.

Comment: This is even more fun if you're looking at the active questions feed where the editor is listed. Looks odd to see a C++ question like, "What's a pointer?" seemingly credited to a user with hundreds of thousands of rep earned in C++ questions.

Comment: This is exactly the reason an answer shouldn’t refer to the author of another question.  It really shouldn’t refer to another answer, since that answer being referred to, could be deleted.  Now if you want to quote another answer, link to that answer, but even then that’s to close to “replying” to an answer for my taste.  Something tells me in this case, the answer that references another answer, probably wasn’t that good.  How about just deleting such a sentence and moving on.  It’s not horrible but certainly not the best answer in the world

Answer (score 1):

Editing this on your own to correct what is in the grand scheme of things a very, very tiny mistake would be more expedient than any other development work or anything else to "resolve" this "issue".